# Finding relationships between a group of nodes looked up from index in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm passing in a group of ids to Neo4J to be looked up through an index. I then want to find those common relationships between them, where 1 node in the collection of found nodes points to another. I'm trying to retrieve the path to do this, but I'd also like the option of just retrieving relationship counts (hence the r on the relationship). So far, I've got something like this:

```
start n = node:idx("MyID:(1 2 3 10000 1500)")
MATCH p=(n)<-[r:RELATED_TO]->(n)
RETURN p
```

However, this always returns nothing, even though I am sure there are common relationships here.

I have looked around but I can't find any examples of anyone doing this in Cypher. How would I go about achieving this? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But you are creating a cartesian product between the two index lookups.

So if those return more than just 5 nodes, it will grow exponentially.

Your query already does 25 path checks (5x5).

```
START n = node:idx("MyID:(1 2 3 10000 1500)")
MATCH p=(n)-[r:RELATED_TO]-(m)
WHERE m.MyId IN [1,2,3,10000,1500]
RETURN p
```

Depending on the number of paths this might be cheaper.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! Its entirely feasible though that I'll have up to a hundred ids. Is having a hundred ids in the where cheaper than 100 extra index lookups?

Comment: great catch - that one is way much cheaper.

Comment: Craig, yes it is otherwise you do 100x100 = 10k path checks. And so you do only follow paths from 100 starting nodes which will probably be less than 10k.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the index lookup twice:

```
start n = node:idx("MyID:(1 2 3 10000 1500)"), 
      m = node:idx("MyID:(1 2 3 10000 1500)")
MATCH p=(n)-[r:RELATED_TO]-(m)
RETURN p
```